# What percentage of troops in the Wehrmacht were front-line combat troops?

Tags: world-war-two, military, nazi-germany

As with every army, a given percentage of the troops are dedicated to the logistics and transport of supplies to support that army’s campaigns. The Wehrmacht of World War Two required a great deal of manpower, munitions and vehicles to support its war efforts. I am not aware of how many troops in the Wehrmacht were dedicated to transporting supplies as opposed to combat, are there any figures to indicate how many troops were key to the logistics and other non-combat functions of the German Army when they were fighting on the most fronts, with the most troops (in late 1944?)

More to the point, how does the German "tail to tooth" ratio compare to that of their battlefield opponents on the western front, like the Americans and British? How about the Soviets on the eastern front?

Comment: logistics men aren't the only non-combat troops. Medics; intelligence; radar & signals ; HQ staff ; almost the whole air force, except pilots and crews; navy ground units;  Then, cooks, engineers, MPs, mechanics, flak, which are 2nd-rate (or worse) for combat but may be embedded in combat units. Also, for the nazis, concentration camp guards, slave labor overseers and the repression apparatus in general (although the SS was not part of the Wehrmacht). And many 2nd-rate units, often non-german, on occupation / anti-partisan duties, or manning defenses in less critical areas.

Comment: I find it a bit irritating that this Q is getting close votes as "too basic, can be answered by a singe WP link or other standard reference source". I for one couldn't come up with such a link. --- As for @Luiz comment, you would have to decide whether you are counting Waffen-SS, "regular" SS, and police units into the total, respectively.

Comment: @DevSolar Agreed on [single link/too basic](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3980/26786)! However, I also do not see any prior research on display… so: (at)Boolean: what have you research yourself beyond ["I once heard"](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2125/26786) into this?

Comment: How do you count concentration guards and other *death squad* personnel? As *front line* or as *logistics*? Also, many *garrison troops* in France and elsewhere would normally be counted as support troops - until landing craft appear on the horizon. So the numbers change over time because the circumstances of various roles change. How is this to be addressed.?

Comment: The question would be stronger with prior research and with clear definitions.  Is there a way to revise it before the downvotes accumulate to closure?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Actually quite a large percentage of *combat troops* never find themselves at the actual front. This does not make them *support* troops, however, just not "front-line" in the meaning OP is probably referring to. Normandy was defended by the 352., 709., and 716. Infantry Division; one a re-formed div., one a garrison div., and one of "volunteers"... By a different token you could say that, by late 1944, none of the Wehrmacht units was actually **fit** for offensive operations (that's by the Germans' own estimate!), so "none" of them were front-line combat troops...

Comment: There is actually a good question at the core of this, but it differs greatly from time to time and from place to place. Often losses were concentrated in frontline units, commanders were reluctant to release trained specialists like signallers or mechanics as riflemen, so over time it got worse until a unit was reorganized.

Comment: Question is rather too broad then too basic . For example, even cooks were expected to fight in case enemy tanks break trough. Luftwaffe and even Kriegsmarine formed units latter in the war that fought like regular infantry. Even SS units like Dirlewanger Brigade, which were not designed for frontline service, were in the end thrown to combat against Soviet regular troops. Perhaps question could be salvaged if changed to something like how many troops were non-combat in standard TOE for Heer Infantry Division, let's say in 1941.

Comment: I made the question less "basic" by asking for the comparison of the German ratios with those of the Allies, America, Britain, and the Soviet Union, and joined the votes to reopen.

Comment: @MCW: There are four reopen votes. If you wish, you can be just a "fifth" vote and not a moderator vote.

Comment: @TomAu This article (at the end) has some of percentages you are looking for (US / German comparison ) https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/opinions/1985/05/05/their-wehrmacht-was-better-than-our-army/0b2cfe73-68f4-4bc3-a62d-7626f6382dbd/